# Looking for value larger than rolling daily average using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called P1, contains datetime index with different date and time, with a trade price column. I would like to find the trade price of each day which are above their corresponding daily average.

```
    P1.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='d')])['Trade Price'].mean()]]
```

This is how i find the daily average

```
   P1.loc[[P1['Trade Price'] > P1.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='d')])['Trade Price'].mean()]]
```

And this is the line i have trouble where i tried to find the row where their trade price at that time of the day are larger than its corresponding daily average.

The error i got: "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

Thanks for you time and i welcome your advice

Comment: use `groupby().transform('mean')` instead of `groupby().mean()`.

Comment: Hi mate, this seems working. thanks a lot